Page not found Using the URLconf defined in kirillof.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
I'm new to Django. I tried to create my first project using a video tutorial from YouTube. When I run my project on the server, it works but the delete my message button does not work
when I run the code, open the server and try to delete my message using the button that I added instead of deleting, this error occurs
use URLconf, right now in kirillof.urls, Django tried out these URL patterns in the following order:
Using URLconf,
The current path, {% url 'delete-message' message.id% }, didn’t match any of these.
You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
I tried to find an error in the url file, but being a newbie I can’t do it
I will be glad for any help
base/views

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/fzsv17u6.png)

base/urls

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/jt3gkSBF.png)




Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post your code as text and not images. The community can help better that way
